# Nonlinear first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $V$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and $x,y:[0,t]\to\in\mathbb{R}$ are smooth. Now consider the nonlinear PDE$$(x^2-x^2(0))e^{2y}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}+x(1-e^{2y})\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)^2=0.$$Can anyone has any idea to solve this kind of PDEs. Charpit's method is not useful here.
Can it possible to use the Hopf-Lax formula for the Hamilton-Jacobi equation in the form of$$H(x,y,DV)=0$$ with BCs $V(\infty,0)=0$.

Comment: You could denote $1/4=\lambda$ as a small parameter, and expand your solution as a series in $\lambda$, and thus find a first order perturbation correction to the linear problem. Higher order corrections are possible as well, even though the calculations would get complicated

Comment: I would also make a substitution $y=\log u$ to get rid of the exponentials